# What are the required outbound IPs and ports on a spigot server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, server-administration, networking, minecraft-spigot

*Note: I am not absolutely sure that the question is on topic, even though [this Meta discussion](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/447/are-questions-regarding-game-server-administration-on-topic) suggests it is. The question is specifically about a game server, not general server administration.*

I run a Spigot (Minecraft) server for my children and friends and would like to limit the outbound connections as much as possible (just in case the server is hacked via the application).

Is there a definite list of IPs which are required for the server to:

- Just run
- Run and make all required checks (of plugin versions for instance)

Ideally, for the first case, this list would be empty (I would check manually from time to time) but it may be that there are some IPs which must be reachable.

As for the second case, I saw a few IPs being reached via HTTP during startup:

```
ec2-54-175-97-178.compute-1.amazonaws.com
ns511765.ip-198-27-66.net
```

They are resolved from more generic names so they are probably round robin ones (or possibly a load balancer, though it should not expose the internal IPs).

Is there an explicit list of the IPs for these servers?

Comment: None of these IP accesses are really necessary - it's mostly just version checking for various things, which are very hard to track down, especially in the case of plugins which can basically implement it however they want. You could essentially block all connections to unknown IPs (except for https://authserver.mojang.com if you want to run the server in online mode), only pretty much losing version checking.

Comment: One thing that may clear up the answers would be to state if you intend on the server be accessable from the internet, or not.

Answer (score 3):

For any Minecraft Server (including custom ones such as *Spigot*, *Sponge* and *Bukkit/CraftBukkit*), these are the only ports and addresses that you require in *and* out-bound traffic allowed to:

- Port 25565 (or whatever number you've set the `server-port` variable in your `server.properties` file) so that clients can connect.
- All client's IPs and handshaked ports.
  *This is dynamic and differs from connection to connection. There isn't really a way to predict the port, but users on the same IP generally means that they're from the same internet connection (within a family household) or VPN... node. With dynamic IP allocation by ISPs, things get a lot more complicated from that point on...* Anyway, moving on;
- `https://authserver.mojang.com` and `http://login.minecraft.net` to handle authentication.
  *Authentication is confirmed both server- and client-side. That's why we have the "User not Premium" error.*

Anything else (due to the nature of plugins in Bukkit/Spigot/Sponge), all those other connections, as you said:

> As for the second case, I saw a few IPs being reached via HTTP during
>   startup:
>
> ```
> ec2-54-175-97-178.compute-1.amazonaws.com
> ns511765.ip-198-27-66.net
> ```

Are probably due to:

- Metrics
- Update Checking
- External Functions (ie. PlotSquared connects to a central server to upload/download schematics when a user chooses to import or export one)

> Is there an explicit list of the IPs for these servers?

Try using a nameserver lookup.

```
ec2-54-175-97-178.compute-1.amazonaws.com = 54.175.97.178  
ns511765.ip-198-27-66.net = 198.27.66.94
```

These are entry-point servers for accepting inputs to cloud services.

Answer (score 0):

For most servers, it isn't necessary to connect to an IP, since they can run without an internet connection. However,  this disables things like `enable-snooper`.

If you are using Spigot, the list is far too dynamic. Spigot changes their software frequently, and plugins might connect to anything. You would need to give the exact spigot version and a list of plugins to generate a list of IPs.